# New RTX 2060 GPU stop working after spark came while plugging in HDMI from PC to TV

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, gpu, tv

It's 1 day old RTX 2060 (just built a new PC). I tried to connect my PC to LG TV using HDMI connection after plugged in the TV cable to electrical connection after power surge. Then, spark came from the connection. After that, my GPU was not detected in from lshw command (Ubuntu). And nvidia-smi command failed.

The day before that event, the PC-TV connection and the GPU was fine. The GPU was detected by lshw, nvidia-smi, Cuda, Tensorflow, etc.

I already plugged out GPU from the motherboard, wait for one day, and reattach the GPU to the motherboard, but still not detected.

Comment: Did the sparks come from the TV end or the GPU end, just in case you noticed it ? Inspect the connectors inside the HDMI cable for any signs of burn marks or damage, if so it's better to buy a new cable.Also inspect the HDMI port at the TV end. Check and make sure if rest of the PC is working or not. In case your CPU has on board GPU you can try using that to check the rest of the PC.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like there was either a short circuit or ground fault.  Try plugging the graphics card into another computer and see if it works.  If it doesnt, it is most likely dead.  If that is the case, your best bet is to try to replace it under warranty.